# jython interpreter startup performance

Tags: jython, jython-2.7

I am embedding Jython (jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar) in a project.
So for every action (which is quite short, think of DB update or similar things implemented in a python script) I start a new interpreter (and close it again afterwards).

The first time I initialize an interpreter, it is starting up quite slowly (Why? can this be accelerated?). For subsequent interpreter initializations, startup seems really fast.

As the actions should be processed quite fast, is it advisable to start a new interpreter all the time or should I use a pool of interpreters instead?

How to reset an interpreter when using an interpreter pool (as there should be no "old" state in the interpreter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since jython is Thread-safe you may just create one interpreter and use it multiple times.

It is also recommanded to execute your jython function/class/import definitions once and only call this dynamically when needed.